# Como reordenar linhas arbitrariamente no R

Tags: r, dataframe

Estou trabalhando com os microdados do Enade e fazendo uma tabela que me dá o percentual dos tipos de presença na prova, esses tipos já definidos na base de dados. Para simplificar, é como se fosse o data frame abaixo:

```
df <- data.frame('Tipo de Presença' = c("Não se aplica", "Resultado válido", "Resultado desconsiderado", "Prova em branco" ),
                 'Presença na Prova' = c(10.05, 89.95, 0.02, 0.08))
```

Gostaria de alterar a ordem das linhas tomando como base a primeira coluna, mas seria uma organização arbitrária, sem considerar ordem alfabética ou de numeração. Nesse caso eu gostaria que as linhas estivessem da seguinte forma: *"Resultado válido"*, *"Resultado desconsiderado"*, *"Prova em branco"* e *"Não se aplica"*.

Já transformei a primeira coluna em factor, e tentei usar **ordered** da forma abaixo, mas não consegui resultado.

```
df <- df %>% mutate('Tipo de Presença' = factor(
'Tipo de Presença',
levels = c("Resultado válido",
           "Resultado desconsiderado",
           "Prova em branco",
           "Não se aplica"),
ordered = TRUE))
```

Alguém tem ideia se é possível?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faltou utilizar a função `arrange()` após o `mutate()`.

```
df1 <- data.frame('PRESENCA' = c("Resultado válido", 
                                 "Resultado desconsiderado",
                                 "Prova em branco", 
                                 "Não se aplica"),
                  'PRESENCA_PROVA' = c(89.95, 0.02, 0.08, 10.05))

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(PRESENCA  = factor(PRESENCA,
                           levels= c("Não se aplica", 
                                     "Resultado válido", 
                                     "Resultado desconsiderado", 
                                     "Prova em branco"))) %>% 
  arrange(PRESENCA)
```

Então teremos o resultado que você esperava.

```
df2


                     PRESENCA PRESENCA_PROVA
 1            Não se aplica          10.05
 2         Resultado válido          89.95
 3 Resultado desconsiderado           0.02
 4          Prova em branco           0.08
```

---

Note que mesmo que no banco de dados `df1` o valor `Não se aplica` tenha ficado por último, o que importa é que em `df2`, ao criar os `levels`, foi indicado `Não se aplica` na primeira ordem. Sendo assim, quando fizer um `arrange`, o R irá interpretar `Não se aplica` como o primeiro level e, portanto, ficará ordenado acima. Caso queira ordenar ao contrário/decrescente, basta utilizar `desc()`, ficando `arrange(desc(PRESENCA))`.

---

Abaixo temos a listagem do ordenamento dos levels na variável PRESENCA

```
levels(df2$PRESENCA)


[1] "Não se aplica"           
[2] "Resultado válido"        
[3] "Resultado desconsiderado"
[4] "Prova em branco"
```

---

Se vale a dica. Evite dar nomes com espaçamento nas variáveis, como no exemplo "Tipo de Presença". O espaço irá gerar complicações futuras em algumas análises, além da complicação de ter que ficar colocando entre aspas para referenciá-la.

Comment: muito obrigado!